# Giving Angular component selector existing html element

Tags: angular

What happens when I set the selector of some component to `div` or `body` or `p`?

The behavior I notice ranges form nothing being rendered to partial rendering and as far as crashing/not loading the page.

Why the inconsistent behavior?

Just wondering, it doesn't throw an error and I couldn't find info on google, obviously you are not supposed to do it, but what happens behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

here the naming convention for angular : [style guide component selector](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-selectors)